# Creating Table of Contents using VSTO and Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

The code below should create a word document and then generate a table of contents. it should only have one item called "INTRODUCTION", but i keep getting an error saying "an unhandled exception of type "system.runtime.interopservicesCOMException" Occured.

```
object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object oEndOfDoc = "\\endofdoc"; /* \endofdoc is a predefined bookmark */

//Start Word and create a new document.
Word.Application oWord = new Word.Application();
Word.Document oDoc = new Word.Document();

oWord.Visible = true;
oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

object oTrue = true;
object oFalce = false;
object styleHeading2 = "Heading 2";
object styleHeading3 = "Heading 3";
oWord.Selection.Range.set_Style(ref styleHeading2);
oWord.Selection.Range.set_Style(ref styleHeading3);

oWord.Selection.Paragraphs.OutlineLevel = Word.WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevel2;
oWord.Selection.Paragraphs.OutlineLevel = Word.WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevel3;
oWord.Selection.Paragraphs.OutlineLevel = Word.WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevelBodyText;

object oBookMarkTOC = "Bookmark_TOC";

Word.Range rngTOC = oDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oBookMarkTOC).Range;  <=== Error Occurs On This Line

rngTOC.Select();

object oUpperHeadingLevel = "1";
object oLowerHeadingLevel = "3";
object oTOCTableID = "TableOfContents";
oDoc.TablesOfContents.Add(rngTOC, ref oTrue, ref oUpperHeadingLevel, ref oLowerHeadingLevel, ref oMissing, ref oTOCTableID, ref oTrue, ref oTrue, ref oMissing, ref oTrue, ref oTrue, ref oTrue);

Word.Paragraph oIntro;
oIntro = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oMissing);
oIntro.Range.Text = "INTRODUCTION";
oIntro.Range.set_Style(ref styleHeading2);
oIntro.Range.Font.Bold = 1;
oIntro.Range.Font.Name = "Arial";
oIntro.Range.Font.Size = 12;
oIntro.Format.SpaceAfter = 15;    
oIntro.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();


Word.Paragraph oPara1;
oPara1 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oMissing);
oPara1.Range.Text = "This is the paragraph after the Introduction Title.";
oPara1.Range.set_Style(ref styleHeading2);
oPara1.Range.Font.Bold = 0;
oPara1.Range.Font.Name = "Arial";
oPara1.Range.Font.Size = 12;
oPara1.Format.SpaceAfter = 15;    
oPara1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

//Update table of contents
oDoc.TablesOfContents[1].Update();
```

Comment: Can you see what the exception message? Maybe use a try-catch or run in debug mode.

Comment: The error occurs on this line Word.Range rngTOC = oDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oBookMarkTOC).Range;
It also says"{"The requested member of the collection does not exist."}"

Comment: I'm not familiar with this API, but would that message imply that "Bookmark_TOC" doesn't actually exist in `Bookmarks`?

Comment: Also, it might help you to decompose the line into multiple statements with each operation on one line (one for `.Bookmarks`, one for `.get_Item`, and one for `.Range`). This should make it clearer exactly which operation is throwing the exception.

Comment: Give your question a meaningful title, please. Currently it's way too broad.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me, try it:

```
selection.Font.Bold = 1;
selection.TypeText("Table of Content\n");  
TableOfContents toc = wordDoc.TablesOfContents.Add(selection.Range, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```